# Maximize $\sum{a_i^2}$ given $\sum{a_i}=237$

Tags: optimization, summation, integer-programming

I recently got stuck with the following problem:

Consider 18 integer numbers in segment $[10; 20]$. Find the maximum possible value of
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{18} {a_i^2}
$$
given that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{18} {a_i}=237$$

I don't really know how to approach this problem. The thing is, solving it like constraint optimization problem I got the solution $a_1=a_2=...=a_n=\frac{237}{18} \approx13.2$

But we need to solve it in integers. And just taking numbers around $13.2$ doesn't make sense to me. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry. Corrected, thanks!

Comment: Thank you!${}{}{}$

Comment: Have you tried the Lagrange multiplier method?

Comment: @mjw Yep, it ended up with non-integer solution

Comment: Okay, I guess you did, and came up with all $a_i$ equal.  This would be the solution if $a_i$ were real.  Perhaps you need to start there, and perturb things a little ... Try some of the $a_i$ are 13 and some are 14 ...

Comment: To add to @mjw's suggestion, the fact that $13.2$ is close to $13$ tells you that most of the numbers should be $13$, and a few will be $14$.

Comment: I also thought like that)) But taking 5x20, 1x17 and 13x10 gives us sum of squares 3589. Which is more than taking 15x13 and 3x14 or some combinations around this.

Comment: Looks like that is a local minimum!

Comment: Are the integers non-negative.  Let $a_1 = M; a_2 = -M; a_3 = 237$.  Then $\sum a_i^2 = 2M^2 + 237^2$ for any $M$.  Certainly not bounded.  But if they must be non-negative then $m>n> 0 \implies (m+1)^2 + (n-1)^2 = m^2 +2(m-n) + n^2 + 2 \ge m^2 + n^2$ with equality holding only if $m=n+1$ by induction $a_k = 237;a_{i\ne k} =0$ will yield highest result if negs aren't allowed.

Comment: If you want to find the *minimum* then you'd like the integers to be as close to the average $13.2$ as possible.  So you will have $k$ terms equal to $14$ and $18-k$ terms equal to $13$ and you will have $14k + 13(18 - k)=237$ or $k = 237-234=3$.  So three terms are $14$ and fifteen terms are $14$.  But that's to find the *MINIMUM* sum of $3*14^2 + 5*13^2 =1433$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to suppose all of the $a_i$ are fixed except for two of them, and see what happens if you add $1$ to one and subtract $1$ from the other.  So say for instance $a_1 = x$, $a_2 = y$, and all the other $a_i$ are fixed.  Then adding $1$ to $x$ and subtracting $1$ from $y$ gives the same sum, but what happens to the sum of squares?  $$(x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2 - (x^2 + y^2)$$ is the amount by which the sum of squares increases or decreases.  But this is $$2x + 1 - 2y + 1 = 2(x-y+1).$$  So if $x \ge y$, this means the sum of squares will increase if we add $1$ to $x$ and subtract $1$ from $y$.  Repeated application of this logic means that the sum of squares is actually maximized when $x$ is as large as possible and $y$ is as small as possible.  Then we repeat this logic for the other terms in the sum; it follows that the maximum is attained when we can make as many of the $a_i$ as large as possible.  Since the $a_i$ are restricted to $[10; 20]$ we want the largest $m$ such that $20 m + 10(18 - m) \le 237$, or $m = 5$.  This means $5$ of the $a_i$ are equal to $20$, $12$ of them are $10$, and the last one makes up the remainder, which has value $17$, and the sum of squares is $3489$.

---

A slightly different way to look at the second part of the solution is to note that since each of the $a_i$ must be at least $10$, we can create an auxiliary sequence $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_{18}$ with $b_i = a_i - 10$, hence $b_i \in [0; 10]$ and the constraint on them is $$\sum_{i=1}^{18} b_i = 57.$$  Then the same reasoning as before gives five $b_i$ equal to $10$, and one $b_i$ equals $7$.

Comment: That's a good one. Thanks!

Comment: this method only proves local optimality, how is this the accepted answer?

Comment: @LevonMinasian This answer is wrong. Look at my answer.

Comment: @Raffaele why do you consider the answer as wrong? Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @LevonMinasian Never mind: I misread. It's totally OK

Comment: @LevonMinasian the reasoning is handwavy at best, it is not clear why $m$ should be as large as possible, because that forces you to pick 17 in the end, which may be suboptimal

Answer (score 4):

An optimal solution cannot have $10 < a_i \leq a_j < 20$ for some $i$, $j$ because that contradicts optimality (you could increment $a_j$ and decrement $a_i$ and get a higher objective value). Therefore, there can be at most one element that is not $10$ or $20$.

There is therefore an optimal solution for which $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ take the value $10$, $a_{m+1},\ldots,a_{17}$ take the value $20$, and $a_{18} \in [10,20] \cap \mathbb{Z}$. From the equality constraint it follows that $a_{18} = 237 - 10m - 20(17-m) = 10m-103$. The only $m$ for which $10m-103 \in [10,20]$ is $m=12$, so the problem is solved.

If you had multiple $m$, you should evaluate the objective value ($100m + 400(17-m) + a_{18}^2 = 100m^2 - 2360m + 17409$) and pick the one for which the objective is the highest.

---

***Other method*** This problem is also easy to solve with an integer programming solver after you formulate it appropriately. Let $x_{10}$ denote the number of times you pick $10$, etc, then the problem is:

\begin{align}
\max_{x} \quad & \sum_{i=10}^{20} i^2 x_i \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \sum_{i=10}^{20} i x_i = 237 \\
& \sum_{i=10}^{20} x_i = 18 \\
& x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_+
\end{align}

I have added the GAMS model below, which you can solve on the NEOS server. The optimal solution is
$$a = (10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,17,20,20,20,20,20)$$

with an objective value of 3489.

```
Set
   i 'idx'    / r10*r20 /;

Parameter
   a(i) / r10 10, r11 11, r12 12, r13 13, r14 14, r15 15, r16 16, r17 17, r18 18, r19 19, r20 20 /;

Integer   Variable x(i);
Variable z;

Equation objective, budget, eighteen_numbers;
objective.. z =e= sum(i, a(i)*a(i)*x(i));
budget.. sum(i, a(i)*x(i)) =e= 237;
eighteen_numbers.. sum(i, x(i)) =e= 18;

Model knapsack / all /;
solve knapsack max z using mip;
```

Comment: Integer programming? Never heard about it. Very interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @LevonMinasian ...but you added the tag 'integer programming' to this question :) I think the reasoning in my answer is more clear than in the accepted answer, could you mark mine as accepted instead?

Comment: no, sorry, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: @LevonMinasian I think the reasoning in my answer is more clear, could you indicate why you do not pick it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for Cauchy's inequality. By Cauchy, we have that $(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2...+a_{17}^2+a_{18}^2)(1+1+1 ... + 1 +1) \ge (a_1(1) + a_2(1) +a_3(1)...a_{17}(1) + a_{18}(1))^2$.

Note that there are $18$ ones in $(1+1+1 ... + 1 +1)$ to pair up with $18$ $a$s.

So, this inequality simplifies as $18(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2...+a_{17}^2+a_{18}^2) \ge (a_1 + a_2 +a_3...a_{17} + a_{18})^2$. We know that the sum on the left is $237$, thus we have $18(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2...+a_{17}^2+a_{18}^2) \ge (237)^2$. Simplifying, we get $(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2...+a_{17}^2+a_{18}^2) \ge 3120.5$. By Cauchy's inequality condition, we must have all $a$ be equal, so we get $18a_1^2 \ge 3120.5$, or $a_1 \le -13.6666$  or $a_1\ge 13.16666...$. However, that means that making all of the terms $13/-13$ actually gets you to the MINIMUM. However, since Cauchy's inequality has no upper bound, that means that the maximum of the squares is INFINITE. This is because you can take ridiculously small negative integers, and ridiculously big integers, and still have a sum of $237$. However, the sum of their squares will be HUGE.

Example, the sum of $-1000,-2000,-3000,-4000,-5000,-6000,-7000,-8000,-9000,-10000,-11000,-12000,-13000,-14000,-15000,-16000,-17000, 153237$

is $237$, but the sum of the squares of this set is $2.5266578169×10^{10}$.

Comment: Actually, I just saw the specification you added, I will make a different answer.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of an answer based on your specifications, I will keep this answer up though, since it shows why your method gives a minimum, not a maximum.

Comment: That's correct thoughts, thanks! I'll upvote just to change your scary rating:)) haha